# Can anyone help me slow down a 3 speed motor?

Tags: motor

I have a 3 speed single phase A/C motor inside an indoor air-con blower and it runs very noisy (not mechanical/installation issue but just the fan moving air is noisy itself) even on its LOW speed setting. Can anyone advise a way to slow the motor speed down to about 50% of its current speed. I'm not too worried about the MED and HIGH speed setting but if can just do for LOW speed setting would be great. (If slow for LOW, MED and HIGH together is also fine.)

I looked at VFD's but they all seem to be for 3-phase motors. Also someone suggested to join the HIGH and MED speed wires on the motor to the LOW speed and at the controller to put HIGH and MED to Ground.

Thanks in advance for any help. Picture attached.

[image]

Comment: What does the data for the motor tell you about possible modifications?

Comment: As a broad general statement, the speed of an AC motor is controlled by the construction of the motor and the AC line frequency. I'm afraid you're not going to get far without a VFD. That said, many VFDs will accept single-phase input, and you might find one that will also power a single-phase motor.  But I suspect you're in the realm of serious control mods at that point, basically bypassing the entire existing speed control.  It will definitely void your warranty.

Comment: Gears. Or pulleys and a belt, probably quieter.

Comment: This is a motor with selectable taps for initial speed setting, rather than it already being a variable speed system under automatic control? If so, the speed *should* have been set to produce the appropriate delta T across the evaporator by balancing the fan performance against the duct resistance - assuming the blower was near correctly sized to begin with. If so, slowing the blower down further risks freezing up the evaporator.   There are single phase VFDs available - effective they're really two phase, as they use the auxiliary winding as a second phase.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies.
Andy: There is no motor specific data. The air-con blower was pre-installed.
Brian: Gears / pulleys are not so practical option as it's pre-fitted to size. It would be a big effort to have to re-mount the motor in the ceiling space.
Phil: Thank you. Maybe single-phase VFD output is the way to go.

Comment: I want to reinforce @PhilG warning, if airflow drops below certain point you may have insufficienct airflow for heat exchanger and operation may go out of working range.

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the voltage.

eg: connect it to 110V instead of to 220V

It's a fan motor it's designed to drive a speed-dependent load and
run at reduced speed by slipping, reducing the supply voltage will
increase the slip and reduce the speed without causing any damage.

Comment: May stall the motor and then cause unexpected heating because airflow is off for motor.

Comment: it's a blower, running the load slower will reduce the torque on a square law,  it's very hard to stall a blower.